# Send notification from web to android device using Firebase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firebase, notifications, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying for a while now to implement this flow: When user adds some files on server app, notification should trigger and send from server to FCM and that from there to pass message saying something like: 'New file has been added'.
Basically I want to inform mobile device user that something on server has been changed.

I have tried many things, but nothing seems to work as I would expect, at least.
On the mobile side I have set up Firebase inside my Xamarin.Android project, and when I am sending notifications directly from Firebase console, I get notifications, and everything is good.

But I don't want to send notifications via Firebase console, I would rather send notification from server (which is ASP.NET MVC project) to Firebase console and then pass it from there to android device.

My first question would be: Has anybody got an idea how can I inform web app about device_id? Is there some way that android device send this information on server? And maybe from there I can store that data and update it occasionally, since it is basically a refresh token.

My second problem is this: Even when I hard code current device_id of an active android device and try to send a message from server whit this code:

```
public class FirebaseService : IFirebaseService
{
    public void SendMessageToClientApplication(string message, string serverApiKey, string senderId, string deviceId)
    {
        AndroidFCMPushNotificationStatus result = new AndroidFCMPushNotificationStatus();

        try
        {
            result.Successful = false;
            result.Error = null;

            deviceId = "eMk6mD8P8Dc:APA91bG5Lmqn4Hwb4RZJ1Mkdl8Rf_uYQsQCEfDJK334tzSvIGzdao7o2X6VmtcTEp_Li0mG8iUoUT7-_RnZxQKocHosZwx6ITWdpmQyCwUv60IIIy0vxNlEaccT6RqK6c-cE1C6I3FTT";

            var value = message;
            WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", serverApiKey));
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));

            string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message="
                + value + "&data.time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + deviceId + "";

            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

                using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                        {
                            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                            result.Response = sResponseFromServer;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Successful = false;
            result.Response = null;
            result.Error = ex;
        }
    }
}
```

I get nothing both in Firebase console and of course nothing on device as well.

I have tried to implement Firebase web as javascript on my server app like this:

```
<script>
    var config = {
        apiKey: "mykey",
        authDomain: "myauthdomain",
        databaseURL: "mydatabaseurl",
        projectId: "myprojectid",
        storageBucket: "mystoragebucket",
        messagingSenderId: "mysenderid"
    };

    window.onload = function () {
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        const messaging = firebase.messaging();

        messaging.requestPermission()
            .then(function () {
                console.log('Notification permission granted.');
                return messaging.getToken()
            })
            .then(function (token) {
                console.log(token);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
            });

        messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
            console.log('onMessage: ', payload);
        });
    }
</script>
```

But this code gets some kind of a different device_id(aka token), probably one generated for that server machine.

Does anybody has experience with sending device_id to server app and from there sending notification message to Firebase console? I would appreciate some code examples, tutorials or anything that can help, since I was unable to find something useful during my google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first question would be: Has anybody got an idea how can I inform web app about device_id?

The most common approach is to store the list of device tokens (each device that uses FCM has such a token) in a database, such as the Firebase Database. There is an example of this in the [Cloud Functions for Firebase documentation](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications). In this example the devices receiving the messages are web pages, but the approach is the same for iOS and Android.

I also recommend reading [Sending notifications between Android devices with Firebase Database and Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html). In this article, instead of sending to a device token, each user [subscribes to a topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging). That prevents having to manage the device tokens in your code.

Comment: Thanks for this links and examples. It's a good start point for me. :) @FrankvanPuffelen